# Как через параметры командной строки передать размер массива?

Tags: java

Осуществляется заполнение массива. Как через Run configurations --> Arguments передать размер массива?

```
int[] c;
Random rnd = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
    c[i] = rnd.nextInt(100);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Аргументом передаете размер массива, парсите это значение из строки в целочисленное, и используете при объявлении нового массива.

```
    int len = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

    int[] c = new int[len];

    Random rnd = new Random();

    for (int i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
        c[i] = rnd.nextInt(100);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Для того,чтобы передать аргументы методу Main() используя Eclipse или Intelij IDE,вам нужно зайти в выпадающий список значка Run Main.Выберите Run Configurations -> Arguments ->Program arguments - сюда вы вводите строки разделяя их пробелом.
Дальше нам нужно обработать аргументы:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
int size = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
int[] array = new int[size];
}
```

Вот и все,для преобразования строки в число используем статический метод класса Integer parseInt.